# Проблема при попытке подключения по имени ДНС

Tags: сеть, curl, ip, dns

у меня такая проблема есть доменное имя допустим name.lol в DNS прописан его IP например 3.3.3.3. При обращении с локального компа к nginx по имени name.lol с помощью curl
*curl name.lol* curl какбудто подвисает и не показывает стартовую страницу заглушку nginx, тоже самое при обращении по внешнему IP 3.3.3.3 а по IP
127.0.0.1 всё отлично работает. Тоже самое с программой вэбклиентом самописной. Я даже думал что дело вэтом самописном клиенте. Но curl ведёт себя также. Как можно исправить?

Comment: А что `curl -v` показывает? Где застревает? https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose

Answer (score 1):

Всё решил, я забыл что закрыл порт снаружи фаерволом)))))